# HierarchyRequestError in IE10 and 11, but not Chrome or IE9

Tags: javascript, xml, internet-explorer-10, internet-explorer-11

I have the following:

```
function getSelectedRowXML(grid)
{
    var selectedIndex = grid.selection.getSelected()[0];

    // Initialise DOM
    var xmlDoc = dojox.xml.parser.parse("<claim></claim>");

    var root = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("claim")[0];

    // Get DOM for the selected row.
    var rowNode = getRowDOMByIndex(grid, selectedIndex);

    root.appendChild(rowNode);

    return dojox.xml.parser.innerXML(xmlDoc);
}

function getRowDOMByIndex(grid, selectedIndex) {
    var xmlDoc = dojox.xml.parser.parse();
    var rowXMLNode = xmlDoc.createElement(grid.xpath);

    // loop round all columns
    for ( var count = 0; count < grid.model.getColCount(); count++) {
    var tagName = grid.structure[0]["rows"][0][count]["headerName"];

    // Create node for data
    var innerXMLNode = xmlDoc.createElement(tagName);

    // Get node value
    var nodeValue = grid.model.data[selectedIndex][count];

        // if it's a date then format it like yyyy-mm-dd
        if (grid.structure[0]["rows"][0][count]["type"] === "Date") {
            var dateParts = nodeValue.split("/");
            nodeValue = (dateParts[2] + "-" + dateParts[0] + "-" + dateParts[1]);
        }
        // Set the value on the newly created node.
        setTextValue(innerXMLNode, nodeValue);
        // Add details to DOM
        rowXMLNode.appendChild(innerXMLNode);
    }

    return rowXMLNode;
}
```

Currently, root contains:

```
<incident></incident>
```

and rowNode contains a list of xml an element with 5 children:

```
<m-incident-priors-list>
  <m-priors-creation-datetime>2014-10-10 11:33:49.613</m-priors-creation-datetime>
  // plus 4 extra...
</m-incident-priors-list>
```

The error occurs at root.appendChild(rowNode). In IE9 and earlier and in Chrome, the error does not occur, the xml is appended successfully and the other methods after these two run as expected. in IE10 and 11 however, a hierarchyRequestError is thrown at the appendChild statement.

Now I've read a few places that this error occurs when a node is appended to itself, Null is appended to a node or a node is appended to a text node but from what I can see, None of these 3 apply to this case.

Is there an alternative method I should be using to append the xml or is there some sort of workaround?

EDIT: Solved the problem, created a method which would determine whether or not the browser was IE, and create an xml doc appropriately. if so, use the original method, if not:

```
xmlDocument= new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
xmlDocument.async=false;
xmlDocument.loadXML(xmlString);
```

Comment: Seems like youre in a hurry but I don't have time for details. Hope this helps. You're trying to move a node from one document into another document. Try `importNode`.

Comment: Not sure if im using importNode correctly, it doesnt seem to add anything to the document if i execute xmlDoc.importNode(rowNode)